# How to remove element from list in Redis by value?

Tags: redis, node-redis

How to remove element from list in Redis by value?

For exmaple, I have:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> lrange POST:544 0 -1
1) "1"
2) "2"
3) "36"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

I know only value `36`, not index. Can I remove element from list by value?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

http://redis.io/commands/lrem

Lrem is what you are looking for. use LREM POST:544 1 36.

Comment: This only works when numeric values are stored in the list right? Tried it with string types stored in the list, but it did not work. Instead I did change the list into a set and now for example this works `SREM myset "four"`.

Answer (score 6):

If the list contains strings then you may enclose it with double quotes then it works!

eg: sampleList ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
If you want to remove "three" then use:

```
LREM sampleList 1 "three"
```